# Hiding Action Bar Sherlock Overflow Menu with three dots

Tags: android

To get a customized overflow menu, I've used sub menu as

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    setupSearchView(searchView);

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Export")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS| MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Import")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add(0, 3, 3, null)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, 2, null);

    subMenu.add(0, 4, 4, "Search Message")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
    .setActionView(searchView)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);


    subMenu.add(0, 5, 5, "Settings")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings);

    subMenu.add(0, 6, 6, "About")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_about);

    MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem();
    subMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow);
    subMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Which gets me action items as

[image]

My only problem is that on wider screens, I am also getting default overflow menu along with my own custom overflow menu. How can I hide default overflow menu?

Comment: Found a hack, which helped me to fix this problem, but still not convinced that this is the best possible way to address such situations. Therefore I am not removing this question, Please help me to find a better solution.

My hack - 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu); 

    menu.getItem(..).setVisible(false);
    

    return true;
}

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have a smiliar problem

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix this using a hack, 

My hack - 
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu); menu.getItem(..).setVisible(false); 
return true;
}